# Lipschitz continuity of $x^{1/3}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is not Lipschitz continuous at $x_0=0$. I am kinda confused so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show your efforts if possible.

Comment: Lipschitz continuous means that the slope is bounded. Find a point where $f$ has unbounded slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terms, all you need is to see that $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$ is unbounded in any neighborhood of $x = 0$. Thus it is not Lipschitz in any interval containing $x = 0$.